# ifconfig en1 inet 4 IP address only (no netmask or broadcast address)

Tags: ifconfig

Is there an elegant way to get just the inet 4 IP address from `ifconfig en1`, i.e without the netmask and broadcast address?

The only way I can get this info currently is:

```
ifconfig en1 | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | cut -f2 -d' '
```

which gives me:

```
10.173.96.150
```

which is correct, but I'd have thought this would be such a common use case that the `ifconfig` program would have provided some more bullet-proof options to specify this.

What I'm trying to do: provide a key binding to a curl command that passes my IP address to some server. Host name won't work unfortunately.

Comment: What does `hostname -I` give you?  It isn't bullet proof, but can be a handy shortcut.

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X (i.e. BSD). So mine doesn't recognize the `-I` option. But that's a good suggestion if I'm on GNU Linux.